# React-Leaflet: Cannot create a Polyline DYNAMICALLY from React Context

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, polyline, react-leaflet

UPDATE!
As Seth Luke asked, why a ref instead of a state, so I did that, and now the lines get drawn! but one step behind. Check out these lines:

```
useEffect(()=>{
        if (drawing) {
                setZonePolygon((prev)=>[...prev, [clickLocation.lat, clickLocation.lng]]);
                setContextData((prevContext)=>({...prevContext, lines: zonePolygon}));
                addZoneMarker();
            }
        }, [clickLocation]);
```

### "lines" in context is getting updated one step behind the local state "zonePolygon"... how do I correct this? Even if I switch the calls, it's the same, the Context gets updated with a delay...
[image]

ORIGINAL POST:

I'm connected to a context in my main map component which contains a . I'm changing the context from another component expecting my map container component to update and re-render the polyline, but it is not happening. What am I doing wrong here? I'm really tired of reading and trying all sort of stuff for over 15 hours no rest now. Could anybody help please? I'd really appreciate it.

My goal is to let the user click different points in the map and have those joined with a line, so that then I can save that as an area or "zone".

This is not being called, I wonder why! I'm using react dev tools to debug and the context does indeed gets the changes, but it's not triggering in the component... so weird.

```
useEffect(()=>{
            console.log('Lines updated in Map component via Context.', lines);
        }, [lines]); // This is not being called, I wonder why!!! ****
```

This is the code I have:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useContext, useRef} from 'react';
import {MapContainer, Marker, Polyline, Polygon, useMapEvent} from 'react-leaflet';
import 'leaflet-rotatedmarker';
import {MapContext} from '../../context/MapProvider';
import Layers from './Layers';
import Ships from '../Ships';

const Map = () => {
    const [map, setMap] = useState(null);
    const {contextData, setContextData} = useContext(MapContext);
    const {clickLocation, drawing, lines} = contextData;
    const [shipData, setShipData] = useState();
        
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log('Lines updated in Map component via Context.', lines);
    }, [lines]); // This is not being called, I wonder why!!! ****



    useEffect(()=>{
        if (!map) return;
        setContextData({...contextData, mapRef: map});
    }, [map]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setShipData(contextData.vessels);
    }, [contextData.vessels]);

    function MapEvents() {
        const map = useMapEvent('click', (e) => {
        setContextData({...contextData, clickLocation: e.latlng});
        });
        return null;
    }

    // const ZONE = [
    //  [-41.95208616893812, -73.52483926124243],
    //  [-42.246913395396184, -73.17047425039003],
    //  [-42.19905906325171, -72.68013196793146],
    //  [-41.936746304733255, -72.81473573174362],
    //  [-41.8118450173935, -73.22404105435608],
    // ]

    return (
        <MapContainer
                center={[-42, -73]} 
                zoom={10}   
                style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}} 
                whenCreated={setMap}>
            <MapEvents />
            <Layers />      
            <Ships data={shipData} />
            {
                (drawing & lines.length > 1) ? <Polyline positions={lines} /> : null
            }
        </MapContainer>
    )
}

export default Map;
```

And this is where I'm modifying the context at:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef, useContext} from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';
import styles from '../../styles.module.scss';
import ZoneItem from './ZoneItem';
import { MapContext } from './../../../../context/MapProvider';

const ZonesBar = () => {
    const {contextData, setContextData} = useContext(MapContext);
    const {mapRef, drawing, lines, clickLocation} = contextData;
    const [zones, setZones] = useState([]);
    const [zoneMarkers, setZoneMarkers] = useState([]);
    let zonePolygon = useRef([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        if (drawing) {
            setContextData((contextData)=>({...contextData, lines: []}));
            zonePolygon.current = [];
        } else if (!drawing) {
            if (zonePolygon.current.length > 2) {
                setContextData((prevContext)=>({...prevContext, zones: [...prevContext.zones, contextData.lines]}));
                setZones((prevZones)=>([...prevZones, zonePolygon.current]));
                clearMarkers();
            }
        }
    }, [drawing]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        if (drawing) {
                zonePolygon.current.push([clickLocation.lat, clickLocation.lng]);
                setContextData((prevContext)=>({...prevContext, lines: zonePolygon.current}));
                addZoneMarker();
            }
        }, [clickLocation]);

    function toggleDrawing() {
        setContextData((prevContext)=>({...prevContext, drawing: !prevContext.drawing}))
    }

    function addZoneMarker() {
        const newMarker = L.marker([clickLocation.lat, clickLocation.lng])
            .addTo(mapRef);
        setZoneMarkers((prevMarkers)=>([...prevMarkers, newMarker]));
    }

    function clearMarkers() {
        zoneMarkers.forEach(m => mapRef.removeLayer(m));
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.zones}>
            <button 
                className={`${styles.btn_add} ${drawing ? styles.btn_drawing : ''}`}
                onClick={toggleDrawing}
                >
                    {drawing ? 'Agregar zona' : 'Definir zona'}
            </button>
            <span style={{fontSize: '0.7rem', fontStyle: 'italic', marginLeft: '0.5rem',}}>
                {drawing ? 'Dar clicks en el mapa para definir la zona, luego presionar el botón otra vez.' : ''}
            </span>

            <div className={styles.list}>
            {
                    zones.length > 0 ?
                    zones.map(zone => <ZoneItem data={zone} />)
                    :
                    'Lista vacía.'
                }                       
            </div>
        </div>  
    )
}

export default ZonesBar;
```

I've changed things up so much now since 9 am today, that I don't know anything else anymore. There's obviously a way of doing this, and I do need some help. If you could take your time to go through this issue that'd be life saving for me.
This is what is looks like, see when I render it with a hard-coded array the polyline comes up.

This is my Context:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, createContext, useContext} from 'react'
import io from 'socket.io-client'
import axios from 'axios';

export const MapContext = createContext();
const socket = io("http://localhost:3001");

const MapProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [contextData, setContextData] = useState({
        mapRef: null,
        clickLocation: [],
        markers: [],
        zones: [],
        drawing: false,
        lines: [],
        vessels: []
    });
    
    // Bring vessels info from API and store in Context.
    useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get('http://localhost:3001/vessel/search/all')
        .then(res => {
            setContextData((prevContext)=>({...prevContext, vessels: res.data}));
        })
        .then(()=>{
            socket.on('vessels', data => {
            setContextData((prevContext)=>({...prevContext, vessels: data}));
            })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err.message));
    }, []);

    return (
        <MapContext.Provider value={{contextData, setContextData}}>
            {children}
        </MapContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default MapProvider;
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post what your `MapContext` looks like?

Comment: My guess would be that the `lines` value in `contextData` isn't triggering a rerender, i.e it's saved in a ref rather than useState.  If that isn't the case it could be a but with the mutability of `positions`.

We use the `@geoman-io/leaflet-geoman-free` library for drawing. It simplifies a lot of stuff and may be a better solution for you.

Comment: Hi Rennzie, thank you for assisting me with this. I posted my Context at the bottom of my question. I'm having a look at the library you suggested as well.

Comment: 1: Respira.  2: Check to see that your useEffect based on `clickLocation` is firing?  Is `zonePolygon` and `lines` being updated in the way you would expect?  Figuring out whether or not your context is actually updating in the way you expect is a huge step in debugging this.  Also, why is `zonePolygon` a ref and not a state variable?  3: Create a codesandbox reproducing the issue and we can really help out. 4: Considering using a well established library to do this like leaflet-geoman or leaflet-editable (though you're very close so I would keep going)

Comment: Agree wit @SethLutske. If you have a codesandbox, we can help out much more

Comment: Hey guys. I created a sandbox but it looks like leaflet is not getting its css and js files to display the map correctly: codesandbox.io/s/sweet-lamport-hok08 
Sounds good Seth, I will go through all the points you mentioned, especially number 1! I wanted to be able to do this simply without libraries, just drawing a line on the map as I click, I hope we can figure it out...

Comment: This is not being called, I wonder why! I'm using react dev tools to debug and the context does indeed gets the changes, but it's not triggering in the component... so weird.       
     
    useEffect(()=>{
          console.log('Lines updated in Map component via Context.', lines);
         }, [lines]); // This is not being called, I wonder why!!! ****

Comment: UPDATE: As Seth Luke asked, why a ref instead of a state, so I did that, and now the lines get drawn! but one step behind. Check out these lines:
 useEffect(()=>{
  if (drawing) {
    setZonePolygon((prev)=>[...prev, [clickLocation.lat, clickLocation.lng]]);
    setContextData((prevContext)=>({...prevContext, lines: zonePolygon}));
    addZoneMarker();
   }
  }, [clickLocation]);

"lines" in context is getting updated one step behind the local state "zonePolygon"... how do I correct this?

Comment: It looks like what Seth Lutske suggested plus some adjustments did the trick. I wish he could post it as an answer so that I accept it as the solution. Please see the answer I posted with new inquiries on a better solution. Thank you guys.

Comment: You don't need to update your question with SOLVED in the title; simply accept the answer that most helped you. See [this help center article on what to do](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: The answer that helped me is a *comment*. How do I accept that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what Seth Lutske suggested in the comments to the original question plus some adjustments did the trick. I wish he could post it as an answer so that I accept it as the solution.

Basically the solution was to use a state hook:

```
const [zonePolygon, setZonePolygon] = useState([]);
```

Instead of a useRef:

```
const zonePolygon = useRef();
```

Then to have the local state and the global Context update in order I split them in different useEffects. This is the working code, but I believe it needs a refactor:

```
useEffect(()=>{
        if (drawing) {
            setZonePolygon((prev)=>[...prev, [clickLocation.lat, clickLocation.lng]]);
            addZoneMarker();
        }
    }, [clickLocation]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        setContextData((prevContext)=>({...prevContext, lines: zonePolygon}));
    }, [zoneMarkers]);
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer probably shouldn't contain a whole new question....as far as elegance goes, I'm not sure what this has to do with Promise.all.  I think your solution is just fine, considering you're trying to recreate leaflet-editable and leaflet-geoman all by yourself.  If it works, it works.  I would edit this answer to explain more clearly what solved this for you, then mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything out of the ordinary. But try moving `MapEvents` outside the `Map` component. Something like

```js
function MapEvents() {
   const {contextData, setContextData} = useContext(MapContext);

   const map = useMapEvent('click', (e) => {
       setContextData({...contextData, clickLocation: e.latlng});
     });

   return null;
}

const Map = () => {
    const [map, setMap] = useState(null);
    const {contextData, setContextData} = useContext(MapContext);
    const {clickLocation, drawing, lines} = contextData;
    const [shipData, setShipData] = useState();
    const linesForPolyline = useRef();

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log('Lines updated in Map component via Context.', lines);
    }, [lines]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        if (!map) return;
        setContextData({...contextData, mapRef: map});
    }, [map]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setShipData(contextData.vessels);
    }, [contextData.vessels]);


    // const ZONE = [
    //  [-41.95208616893812, -73.52483926124243],
    //  [-42.246913395396184, -73.17047425039003],
    //  [-42.19905906325171, -72.68013196793146],
    //  [-41.936746304733255, -72.81473573174362],
    //  [-41.8118450173935, -73.22404105435608],
    // ]

    return (
        <MapContainer
                center={[-42, -73]} 
                zoom={10}   
                style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}} 
                whenCreated={setMap}>
            <MapEvents />
            <Layers />      
            <Ships data={shipData} />
            {
                (drawing & lines.length > 1) ? <Polyline positions={lines} /> : null
            }
        </MapContainer>
    )
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: Hey Rennzie, same thing... what was your idea with this? I'm using the react dev tools and the context does seem to be updating and catching the map events.